# Cross geometry collection for a set of geometry collection

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection

I have a set of geometry collection that I want to intersect in order to get a geometry collection containing the cross collection of all this set.
I tried to use 'intersection' method but this just compute the shared geometry between two geometry, it does not return a collection of geometrie representing the cross of two geometry.

If someone knows a good way to do this, I will appreciate it!

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific about what are the geometric primitives used in your geometry. In any case, I suggest you use a computational geometry library like [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). Represent your geometric primitives using its classes and it has functions to compute the intersections of all types of primitives.